# fullcalendar - remove dragged external events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using a variation of the FullCalendar external dragging demo, found here:

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/external-dragging.html

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to remove an event that you added through external dragging by double clicking it. Something like this:

```
              $('.fc-event').dblclick(function(){
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );
                  });
```

Now this will work... at removing all of the events. removeEvents's documentation can be found here:

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/

Essentially, the problem is that I can't have something like this:

```
              $(**idOfTheEvent**).dblclick(function(){
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', **idOfTheEvent** );
                  });
```

because there may be many of the same events. By having multiple "Event 2"s, for example, double clicking on one of them would remove them all. So that's out.

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
              $(.this).dblclick(function(){
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', .this );
                  });
```

utilizing "this". However, this wouldn't work either since I can only use event objects or IDs within removeEvents's parameters. So I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to use eventClick native event from fullcalendar. With this you have access to id of the specific element that you're clicking